# 'perl' is not recognized as an external or internal command *Help configuring strawberry perl!*

Tags: perl

I am teaching myself Perl, and I have installed Strawberry on my Windows 8 64 bit system.  The Strawberry command line seems to work fine, and I have created a new folder in my Strawberry folder on my C drive to place my practice files (created in Notepad++) in.

I change to my directory containing the .pl files (which in my case is C:\Strawberry\programs), and try to run a program, for ex. perl practice1.pl.  When I do this it says 'perl' is not recognized as an external or internal command.  Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Set path,

Path :-  Path is the OS Envirnment varialbe that used by OS to find executable files, you can find how to set path on google easily

if you don't want to set path then another solution is also there  :-

Consider your perl  is installed in this location :-

c:\perl\perl.exe

and your .pl files are in  "Strawberry" folder that is in c drive ex:-

c:\Strawberry\perl_script1.pl
c:\Strawberry\perl_script2.pl  etc.

then open cmd and navigate to perl directory  ,

> c:\perl\

use perl.exe and give the complete path of those files as argument

so for perl_script1.pl  it will be

> c:\perl\perl c:\Strawberry\perl_script1.pl   // and same for other script also

Thanks :)